# putImageData is "darkening" the image

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas

I have two canvas. In the first canvas I draw an image and the second canvas I copy the image from the first canvas and paste in the second canvas by using the "getImageData" e "putImageData"

The following code is a small piece of the code that I have on my application. I cut off the parts that was not causing the issue and compact it. [Note that the image present in the javascript needs to exists "image3.jpg"].

```js
var canvasLocal = document.getElementById('c'),
 context = canvasLocal.getContext('2d'),
 canvasToRender1 = document.getElementById('c2'),
 ctx = canvasLocal.getContext("2d"),
 canvasToRender1Ctx = canvasToRender1.getContext('2d'),
 base_image = new Image();

base_image.src = 'imagem3.jpg';
base_image.onload = function() {
 canvasLocal.width = canvasToRender1.width = base_image.width;
 canvasLocal.height = canvasToRender1.height = base_image.height;
 
 context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
  
 var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, base_image.width, base_image.height);

 
 canvasToRender1Ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2"></canvas>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is that the image on the second canvas looks darken that the original one:

[image]

I tested in several browsers but the only one that I could see the issue was the chrome for android which the android version is equals or greater than 6.0.1. (The chrome version was the 57.0.2987.132 for all phones that we tested).

**UPDATE: I already report the issue to chromium.** 
Check it on this link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=713632#

Comment: I would have a three letter comment starting with a W, ending by a F and with a T in the middle. I know you've got a workaround, but just by curiosity, can you reproduce with any image? Does your original image have a color profile embedded?

Comment: Yes I can. And I tested with different images with different sizes and also with different canvas sizes. It is really strange. Let see what google chrome guys says to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the solution is to use the drawImage instead of the putImageData.

Follows the code with the issue solved:

```
var canvasLocal = document.getElementById('c'),
context = canvasLocal.getContext('2d'),
canvasToRender1 = document.getElementById('c2'),
ctx = canvasLocal.getContext("2d"),
canvasToRender1Ctx = canvasToRender1.getContext('2d'),
base_image = new Image();

base_image.src = 'imagem3.jpg';
base_image.onload = function() {
     canvasLocal.width = canvasToRender1.width = base_image.width;
     canvasLocal.height = canvasToRender1.height = base_image.height;

     context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);

}
```

Comment: So, if I'm getting the image data, modify it and I cannot use drawImage in this case then I need to wait untill chrome will resolve the issue?

Comment: Probably. In my case this worked well. For your case I don't know if there is another solution then wait for the chrome fix

Comment: @RicardoRocha  can you post bit more code? for me it looks like canvasToRender1 does not do a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Found resolution for the case when modifying pixels is necessary.
You can use `ImageBitmap`.

```js
return createImageBitmap(imageData).then(function(bitmap){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = bitmap.width;
    canvas.height = bitmap.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
});
```