# Why image gets very dark when resized in canvas using Chrome for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, html5-canvas, image-resizing

I am using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9g9Nv/519/) to reproduce my problem. Using Chrome for Android from version 57, resized image gets very dark. If you resize image enough (varies from phone to phone) darkness disappears and image is resized correctly.

Anyone has any ideas what could be causing this strange behaviour ? I have [filed a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=715399#) in Chromium, however I don't expect it to be resolved any time soon. And I need to fix it as soon as possible, because I am using this code in production and it's causing major problems.

SO wants me to put some code, because I have used link to jsfiddle, so this is part of the code which is causing this problem which I use for resizing images using HTML5 canvas:

```
/**
     * Hermite resize - fast image resize/resample using Hermite filter. 1 cpu version!
     * 
     * @param {HtmlElement} canvas
     * @param {int} width
     * @param {int} height
     * @param {boolean} resize_canvas if true, canvas will be resized. Optional.
     */

this.resample_single = function (canvas, width, height, resize_canvas) {
    var width_source = canvas.width;
    var height_source = canvas.height;
    width = Math.round(width);
    height = Math.round(height);

    var ratio_w = width_source / width;
    var ratio_h = height_source / height;
    var ratio_w_half = Math.ceil(ratio_w / 2);
    var ratio_h_half = Math.ceil(ratio_h / 2);

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width_source, height_source);
    var img2 = ctx.createImageData(width, height);
    var data = img.data;
    var data2 = img2.data;

    for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            var x2 = (i + j * width) * 4;
            var weight = 0;
            var weights = 0;
            var weights_alpha = 0;
            var gx_r = 0;
            var gx_g = 0;
            var gx_b = 0;
            var gx_a = 0;
            var center_y = (j + 0.5) * ratio_h;
            var yy_start = Math.floor(j * ratio_h);
            var yy_stop = Math.ceil((j + 1) * ratio_h);
            for (var yy = yy_start; yy < yy_stop; yy++) {
                var dy = Math.abs(center_y - (yy + 0.5)) / ratio_h_half;
                var center_x = (i + 0.5) * ratio_w;
                var w0 = dy * dy; //pre-calc part of w
                var xx_start = Math.floor(i * ratio_w);
                var xx_stop = Math.ceil((i + 1) * ratio_w);
                for (var xx = xx_start; xx < xx_stop; xx++) {
                    var dx = Math.abs(center_x - (xx + 0.5)) / ratio_w_half;
                    var w = Math.sqrt(w0 + dx * dx);
                    if (w >= 1) {
                        //pixel too far
                        continue;
                    }
                    //hermite filter
                    weight = 2 * w * w * w - 3 * w * w + 1;
                    var pos_x = 4 * (xx + yy * width_source);
                    //alpha
                    gx_a += weight * data[pos_x + 3];
                    weights_alpha += weight;
                    //colors
                    if (data[pos_x + 3] < 255)
                        weight = weight * data[pos_x + 3] / 250;
                    gx_r += weight * data[pos_x];
                    gx_g += weight * data[pos_x + 1];
                    gx_b += weight * data[pos_x + 2];
                    weights += weight;
                }
            }
            data2[x2] = gx_r / weights;
            data2[x2 + 1] = gx_g / weights;
            data2[x2 + 2] = gx_b / weights;
            data2[x2 + 3] = gx_a / weights_alpha;
        }
    }
    //clear and resize canvas
    if (resize_canvas === true) {
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width_source, height_source);
    }

    //draw
    ctx.putImageData(img2, 0, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that the same issue is already asked here: [putImageData is "darkening" the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515988/putimagedata-is-darkening-the-image)

My bug report was merged into this chromium issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=713632#c24